# Is it expected that the extension Vetur for VS Code doesn’t auto-complete in HTML files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I only started learning Vue.js 2 and I use [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with [Vetur](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur) for that.

However, I noticed that Vetur's auto-completion only works in .Vue files but not html or vue-html formats.

As example, in a file like this: (xxx.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Vue.JS Tutorial </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="App.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="vue-app">
    <h1> My Profile </h1>
    <button @click="add(10)">Add 10 years</button>
    <button @click="subtract(20)">Subtract 10 years</button>
    <p>My age is: {{age}}</p> 
    <div id="canvas" @mousemove="updateXY">
      <p>{{x}}, {{y}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  
</body>

</html>
```

That is linked to this file (.JS):

```
new Vue({
  el: "#vue-app",
  data: {
    age: 25,
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(addnum) {
      this.age += addnum;
    },
    subtract: function(minusnum) {
      this.age -= minusnum;
    },
    updateXY: function(event) {
      this.x = event.offsetX;
      this.y = event.offsetY;
    }
  }
});
```

The completion doesn't work at all. When I write something like `v-` as an attribute, nothing shows to me and I have to write it myself.

Even in the .JS file (which is supposed to be a Vue file) nothing related to Vue works except the syntax highlighting.

Is that normal or a problem I have to fix? If it's a problem, what is the fix?

Comment: yes I guess vetur is only for .vue files

Comment: @Sandro Is there any other way around it? Also an unrelated question but what's the difference between a Javascript file that uses "new Vue" and a .vue file? I think that it has something to do with single file components or something like that but I didn't understand it.

Comment: no, vscode can't link the two files together, because it can't be sure how your web server is going to work (perhaps it's going to replace App.js with something else?)...

Comment: yes, .vue files are single file components. they're great to work with but need a compiler/transpiler thingy.

Comment: @Sandro oh okay then. Sigh, I feel bad that I now follow Net Ninja but it doesn't learn how to use single file components. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: np. you can check out https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html to learn more about SFC.